# Where do stock traders get realtime updates on Fed announcements? Is there a feed I could scrape?

Tags: online-data-source, federal-reserve

Upcoming Fed announcements are important, and I want to get the news in realtime when it happens. I know there are a few expensive services, but I'm looking for some feeds that can be scraped or accessed through similar methods.

Comment: Bloomberg console etc are obviously very expensive https://bba.bloomberg.net/Install/Client - is there any cheap alternative

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tthe easiest place to see Fed announcements as soon as they're published is the Federal Reserve itself. If you want the information as soon as it's made publicly available, scrape the [Federal Reserve press releases](http://www.federalreserve.gov/newsevents/press/all/2013all.htm). I assume you're most interested in the announcements after the FOMC meetings, so you might want to scrape the [FOMC calendar](http://www.federalreserve.gov/monetarypolicy/fomccalendars.htm). The statements come out right after the meeting, and the minutes are released [three weeks later](http://www.richmondfed.org/faqs/fomc/).

If you want to catch instances where the minutes are [leaked](http://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/wonkblog/wp/2013/04/10/oops-fed-minutes-inadvertently-released-early-show-a-divided-fomc/), that's a bit trickier.

For a lot of other market data, services providers like Bloomberg, Reuters, etc. are usually the best bet for realtime information, since these companies earn their revenue and keep their customers by providing the data as fast as humanly possible. They may offer an *analysis* or a distilled version of the FOMC minutes for traders to use within minutes of the announcement itself (I'm not sure if they do or not), but the announcements themselves will come from the Federal Reserve itself first and foremost.

Answer (score 1):

Bloomberg terminal is a pretty standard way nowadays to get this information (and a lot more) pretty much in real time.